# Spring boot Base64 String as mail attachment

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I converted a PPTX file into Base64 string and now i want to use this string as an email attachmen

i used to use this part of code for sending file from local path and it works fine

```
   public void sendEmail(Mail email) throws MailException, MessagingException {

        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setTo(email.getEmail());
        helper.setText(email.getMessage());

        FileSystemResource file  = new FileSystemResource(email.getPath());
        helper.addAttachment("testfile.pptx", file);

        helper.setSubject(email.getSubject());
        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }
```

what i must change/add to send this base64 string as an attachement file ?  . thank you

Comment: Why did you encode it? Don't, the mail-api will take care of it, just attach the original file.

Comment: @M.Deinum i want to send the  presentation without saving it on my machine ,  i got the base64 string from the client side ( Angular 8 )

Comment: Why would you need to store it? You are already storing it, judging from the fact you are using a `FileSystemResource`. If you don't want to store it then just read the inputstream (or byte[]) when it is part of the form object you are submitting.

Comment: @M.Deinum first thnak you for your comment , i  don't want to save the presentation on my machine i just converted the PPTX file into a base64 string from the client side  and send it as an email attachment ,  and it works thanks to your comment i used  byte[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it

```
public void sendEmail(Mail email) throws MailException, MessagingException {

    MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
    helper.setTo(email.getEmail());
    helper.setText(email.getMessage());
    byte[] doc = Base64.getDecoder().decode(email.getBase64());

    helper.addAttachment("doc.pptx", new ByteArrayResource(doc));

    helper.setSubject(email.getSubject());
    javaMailSender.send(message);
}
```